# Jquery UI SORTABLE AND DROPPABLE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

All `TR` are sortable and what i want to achieve is:

As soon as i start dragging a `TR` the placeholder is replaced with some sort of same structure as the dragged `TR`.

When i drag a `TR` i should be able to hover over the first 6 `TD` of that dragged `TR`. But my problem is that when i start dragging the hover works correctly, but as soon as i move the `TR` the hover doesn't work properly anymore.

Example:
If i drag the third `TR` and hover over the `TD` it works fine.
As soon as i drag to the second `TR`, the hover `TD` doesn't work anymore, unless i move to the first `TD`than it works again properly.

Javascript:

```
$(".OssDataSortable").sortable({
    items: 'tr',
    opacity: 0.00001,
    placeholder: 'OssDataSortablePlaceholder',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    axis: "y",
    dropOnEmpty: false,

    activate: function(event, ui) {
      var ii = 0;

      $(ui.placeholder).html('<td id="level_0" class="OssDataDroppable">0</td>')
        .append('<td class="OssDataDroppable">1</td>')
        .append('<td class="OssDataDroppable">2</td>')
        .append('<td class="OssDataDroppable">3</td>')
        .append('<td class="OssDataDroppable">4</td>')
        .append('<td class="OssDataDroppable">5</td>')
        .append('<td>text .....</td>');


      $(".OssDataDroppable").droppable({
        tolerance: "pointer",
        activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
        hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
        over: function(event, ui) {
          $("#DROP_NUMBER").val($(this).text());
        }
      });
    }

  });
```

HTML:

```
<tbody class="OssDataSortable">
      <tr class="OssDataDraggable">
        <td valign="middle" style="min-width:28px;"></td>
        <td valign="middle" style="min-width:28px;"></td>
        <td valign="middle" style="min-width:28px;"></td>
        <td valign="middle" style="min-width:28px;"></td>
        <td valign="middle" style="min-width:28px;"></td>
        <td valign="middle" style="min-width:28px;"></td>
        <td valign="middle">
          ARTICLE 1
        </td>
      </tr>
     .......
      <tr class="OssDataDraggable">
        <td valign="middle" style="min-width:28px;"></td>
        <td valign="middle" style="min-width:28px;"></td>
        <td valign="middle" style="min-width:28px;"></td>
        <td valign="middle" style="min-width:28px;"></td>
        <td valign="middle" style="min-width:28px;"></td>
        <td valign="middle" style="min-width:28px;"></td>
        <td valign="middle">
          ARTICLE 4
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZtIYdq4oFSSvZ4ycrk68?p=preview

tks.

Comment: Hi, a fiddle or plnkr is great. But your question should always include valid code also.

Comment: Hi, I added main javascript function, and HTML sample. It's ok ?

Comment: It semms normal that it act like this. In the `activate` function, you add `OssDataDroppable` cellss to the current row of the placeholder. You should add these cells to the helper I think.